# Is there any side effect with using GitHub Extensions for Visual Studio and TFS side by side?

Tags: github, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I use Visual Studio 2015+TFS for my work projects. Visual Studio 2015 works flawlessly with TFS - of course.

I am doing a few personal projects (pet projects) on my leisure time and I have them on GitHub.

None of my projects use GitHub or TFS at the same time. It is either TFS or Github.

I am thinking to install [GitHub Extensions for Visual Studio.](https://visualstudio.github.com/); however, I am concern that it might have some side effect with my work projects that are hosted on TFS.

I wanted to consult here and check if anyone has encountered any interference between   GitHub Extensions for Visual Studio and TFS  client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no side effect with using GitHub Extensions for GitHub and TFS, just make sure you have separate workspaces for GitHub projects and TFS projects.

When you work on GitHub projects, login GitHub and clone or create projects, then VS will connect to your GitHub:

[image]

When you work on TFS projects, connect to your TFS, and VS will connect to your TFS:

[image]